# Node.js and piping a ConnectionListener

Tags: node.js, pipe

The [Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/net.html) provides an example for creating an echo server:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (c) {
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, 'localhost');
```

What purpose does this line serve?

```
  c.pipe(c);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`c1.pipe(c2)`; is a short version for

```
c1.on('data', function(buf) { c2.write(buf); });
```

(plus 'drain' event handling, pause/resume etc - see [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options))

So `c.pipe(c)` means 'echo data sent to c'.

Comment: Your explanation should be added to the node API docs. Thanks!

Comment: Best explanation ever!

Comment: OK, i think the answer is still not clear enough to me as the purpose, so basically this `c.pipe(c)` here does this job: whatever data the socket c receives, it will send it back to the client.